# How to fix the column for the time measurement

Tags: python, excel, pandas, time

I would like to measure the execution time of a program by using python and pycharm.
Here is the code that I used.

```
import time
import pandas as pd

# get the start time
st_wall = time.time()
st = time.process_time()


df_time = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Total Execution time (s)','CPU Execution time (s)'])


# get the end time
et_wall = time.time()
et_process = time.process_time()

# get execution time
wall_clock_time = et_wall - st_wall
res = et_process - st

# get execution time
wall_clock_time = et_wall - st_wall
res = et_process - st

print('Total Execution time:', wall_clock_time, 'seconds')
print('CPU Execution time:', res, 'seconds')

time_row={'Total Execution time (s):': wall_clock_time, 'CPU Execution time (s)':res}
df_time = df_time.append(time_row, ignore_index=True)

#import data to excel
datatoexcel = pd.ExcelWriter('lambda summary by setting random range sample size 100.xlsx')

# write DataFrame to excel
df_time.to_excel(datatoexcel, sheet_name='Calculation Time')

# save the excel
datatoexcel.save()
print('DataFrame is written to Excel File successfully.')
```

The expected result is:
[image: expected result]

However, the current result from the code is as follows.
[image: current result]

Could anyone let me know what needs to be revised, please?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. Are you trying to record multiple runs of the function into a table? I'm not sure why you create an empty dataframe and then append one run to it (note, I got an error saying that the append function in pandas is soon to expire).

I'm not sure about excel because I do not have excel, but I produced a code that populates a dataframe for muliple runs. Using your code, I'm assuming the dataframe it will save to excel correctly.

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math


def func(x):
    L=[]
    for i in range(1000000):
        a=math.sqrt(x^5)
        L.append(a)
    return np.sum(L)

total_list=[]
cpu_list=[]

for i in range(10):
    # get the start time
    st_wall = time.time()
    st = time.process_time()

    func(1000)

    # get the end time
    et_wall = time.time()
    et_process = time.process_time()

    # get execution time
    wall_clock_time = et_wall - st_wall
    res = et_process - st

    total_list.append(wall_clock_time)
    cpu_list.append(res)

df_time=pd.DataFrame({'Total Execution time (s):': total_list, 'CPU Execution time (s)': cpu_list})
print(df_time)

#import data to excel
datatoexcel = pd.ExcelWriter('lambda summary by setting random range sample size 100.xlsx')

# write DataFrame to excel
df_time.to_excel(datatoexcel, sheet_name='Calculation Time')

# save the excel
datatoexcel.save()
print('DataFrame is written to Excel File successfully.')
```